# How to return encoded value using subprocess.Popen in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen, with-statement

Can someone tell me how to encode the return statement so that it can decode it.
Or whats needs to be changed to get encoded value.

> Code

```
def run_process(cmd_args):
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
        return proc.communicate()


res = run_process(cmd_args);
print(res)
print(res.decode("utf-8"))
```

> Output

```
print(res.decode("utf-8"))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Popen.communicate` returns a tuple of `(stdout, stderr)`, so you need to treat the returning value as such:

```
stdout, stderr = run_process(cmd_args);
print(stdout)
print(stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

Please read [`Popen.communicate`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) for more details.

Comment: Got it ! @blhsing , Thank you so much

    stdout, stderr = run_process(cmd_args);

this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

instead of return proc.communicate(),return proc.communicate()[0].
As proc.communicate() is a list of output and error and it seems u only need output part